# Display current playback speed in VLC

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

Is there any way to display current playback speed in VLC? Right now I have to decrease or increase the playback speed, which is not convenient:

[image]

I use the latest version of VLC (2.1.3) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the `View` menu of VLC player, Click the `Status Bar` , so that the current speed will be displayed on the status bar always. You can enable this for full screen also.

[image]

If you click on the speed indicator, you can adjust the speed accurately as follows:
[image]

This method works in any versions.

To enable it in Full screen:Click `Tools-Customize Interface..` you'll get *toolbars editor*, drag the `Speed selector` tool to full screen interface as follows and click `Close`:

[image]
Additional information: Installing the 64-bit version is better, since you are using 64-bit OS.

Comment: "Accurately" is a bit of an overstatement here. It seems to only allow values (1, 1.04, 1.09, 1.13, 1.18, 1.23, ...) for me, even when I use arrow keys instead of mouse. I don't believe this is a technological limitation as `Speed > Faster (fine)` allows 1.1 etc. They should just let the user input it directly.

Comment: I think this isn't available on Mac (in my experience and in this person's https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/250868/53510).

Comment: Damn, here I am again years later and seeing my previous comment. I'm disappointed that the VLC interface isn't better on Mac.

Answer (score -1):

Enable OSD (On Screen Display) which will enable on Screen

Comment: We always appreciate contributions from our community members, but can you please elaborate and explain *how* to do that?