# How to change playback speed steps in VLC Player?

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player, speed, video-playback

I am using VLC player as my video and audio player on Ubuntu (14.04).
In playback menu under speed item, I can choose `Faster (fine)` or `Slower (fine)` to speed up or down playback. But it changed speed by 10% steps. I need 5% steps. Is there any way to change this step?

Answer (score 22):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/782409/519460).

> In the `View` menu of VLC player, Click the `Status Bar` , so that the current speed will be displayed on the status bar always. You can enable this for full screen also.
>
> [image]
>
> If you click on the speed indicator, you can adjust the speed accurately as follows:
>   [image]

Note that this limits you to weird increments. For me it is (1, 1.04, 1.09, 1.13, 1.18, 1.23, 1.28, 1.33, 1.39, ...) even when I use arrow keys instead of the mouse.

Comment: `[` and `]` use 0.1 step size.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman yes but I'm talking about using _the mouse_ which results in a different step size

Comment: Yeah, but like you also said, those increments are messed up.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman yes but OP's problem was that 0.1 steps were **too large** so they wanted 0.05 steps

Comment: Hence my comment instead of an answer; it merely adds to your answer regarding funky step size.

Answer (score 5):

In `Tools > Preferences > All > Input / Codecs` you can find an option for `Playback Speed`.

[image: The "Tools > Preferences" window on Linux Mint]

You can enter any value there **up to 0,01 precision**. The up/down buttons on the right change the playback speed in 0,10 increments.

**Restart VLC** for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

playitslowly Install playitslowly

Different to the suggestion of the application's name this player is able to change to a higher or lower pitch or to different playback speeds. Also included is the ability to loop over a section of the audio file (for transcription purposes), and to save the file at a given different speed.

The package is in the repositories (universe) from Ubuntu 11.04. Here is the project's home page. The player is based on gstreamer, so any files compatible with that will be played.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.